# DAO database only references the first record in a table, meant to put it into specific record - Microsoft Access Code

Tags: vba, ms-access

At the moment, it takes an image I add to my signature folder and puts it straight into the attachments field of my contract. HOWEVER! It does not put it into the specific record for which the button is pressed- it puts the image into the signature box of the first record every time. I am new to SQL, how would I go about making it

So below is my code:

```
Private Sub Command21_Click()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset2
Dim strFile As String

Set db = CurrentDb()
strFile = "C:\Users\Reception\Desktop\Files\Signature\sign.png"

Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("Table1")

rs1.Edit
Set rs2 = rs1!GuestRegistration.Value


With rs2
    .AddNew
    !FileData.LoadFromFile strFile
    .Update
End With

rs1.Update

Form.Refresh

Set rs2 = Nothing
Set rs1 = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!! Sorry I am so novice.

I tried a few things but I don't understand enough about coding to know what I was doing. I am still a beginner doing this for my business. I just need it to pt the image in the correct record rather than instantly putting it in the first record of the recordset.

Comment: Open recordset filtered to specific record. What field on form would be unique identifier? `"SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ID=" & Me!ID`. Embedding images in table uses Access 2GB file size limit. Store image path string in text field and Image can stay in folder and be pulled when need.

Comment: Are you really saving same image in multiple records? Is your table really named Table1?

Comment: I have left my primary key as ID, so that is the unique identifier. I don't know how that line of code necessarily helps me achieve what I want to do. I am just met with a syntax error. 

They aren't the same image, I am using a digital signature pop-up for guests to sign. It saves that signature as a temporary png, which then gets put onto the guest registration. Contracts are terminated every year, and these pngs are worth 6KB each, so we will not reach the 2GB limit within that, as we are constantly removing as we add new guest contracts.

Comment: @June7 was I meant to use that line of code somewhere specific to call to it? I assumed within the with rs2 at the start, but all I got was the compile error: Expected: line number or label or statement or end of statement

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind!! Thank you so much @June7 for the response! I set his response code as a string and referenced it instead of Table1 so it isolates only the record I wanted. Find attached my code below if you need this for help with any projects :)

```
Private Sub Command21_Click()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset2
Dim strFile As String
Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ID=" & Me!ID
Set db = CurrentDb()
strFile = "C:\Users\Reception\Desktop\Files\Signature\sign.png"

Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

rs1.Edit



Set rs2 = rs1!GuestRegistration.Value

With rs2
    .AddNew
    !FileData.LoadFromFile strFile
    .Update
End With

rs1.Update

Form.Refresh

Set rs2 = Nothing
Set rs1 = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```